# How to create a dynamic/modular 3-piece form input with html, JavaScript, and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I had no success researching this problem, so apologies for my difficulty in concisely describing it.

Basically, I'm building a website where users can submit "recipes," by way of html form > php. I wanted a way then for users to dynamically add or subtract steps or ingredients (I've seen this on other sites, but I couldn't find a simple pure js solution).

Anyway, I built something akin to what I wanted ([example here](https://www.experimonkey.com/discover/experiments/submit/example.php), [JavaScript here](https://www.experimonkey.com/js/scripts/changeform.js)), but I'm not convinced it's such a great solution. To retrieve the form info, the php code basically loops through the materials' and steps' ids until it's reached the last one.

Although this solution works, I've run into 2 more problems:

The first is that the text for each input is saved in a js array each time the user types--that way new inputs can be added or removed without losing the text. However, when a new input element is created, if this previous text was too long, it is cut off.

The second is that for the ingredients section, I'd like to have a  element where users can only choose standardized measurements (ie mg, g, kg...) and then another  for a numeric quantity. I've tried Bootstrap's input-group classes, but the spacing turns out very odd and doesn't work at all on mobile. Is there a better way to accomplish this? This also thoroughly complicates the my original solution, since there will now be 3x as many inputs.

Comment: You do realize how vague your question is, no?
To put it differently: what kind of answers do you expect to receive?
Posting a question with title "how to create ..." means you are waiting for someone to answer with a guide? (!)
First, you start describing the architecture of your solution to the problem, comparing it to an example you found which you seem not to like.
Second, you state two minor problems which you should be able two resolve if you understood the code indeed.
To sum up, your question is most **unclear**. Please define the problem, divide it to sub-problems and correct it.

Comment: @SlinkySloth I do, but I'm not sure how to make it more clear or concise, which is part of my problem. The examples I posted are of my current solution, and I thought were reasonably descriptive to what I was trying to accomplish. Would you be able to look at that first link and give me an idea of how to proceed in describing my problem? Apologies for the trouble.

Comment: As far as your first problem is concerned, I tried your example in latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and Edge. No such issue appears or at least I didn't notice such. After how many characters did you notice the text cutting off?
Regarding your second issue, you can use Bootstrap's margins and paddings as well as vertical and horizontal aligns together with input group (please read thoroughly [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/), [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) and [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/) )

Comment: That's really odd, I couldn't recreate the problem either... but I've noticed it several times. I'll have to keep investigating. And thanks also for the links, I guess I should've looked more thoroughly to begin with.